# Unable to create a file in specified path in linux?

Tags: linux

I am unable to create either a file or a directory in a specified path in Linux. 
I am getting the error "No space left on device". 
I have checked with `df -k` and `df -i`. Free disk space is 28 % and free inodes are 28 %. 
What else could be the reason?

Comment: What file system?

Comment: where do you want to create ur file/folder?

Comment: @nemo:                                                                                   
file system is ext3

Comment: @stuti:
in the path where my application is running

Comment: @nemo:
how is it related to file system type?

Comment: @abcd: I have seen this problem with huge (10s of terabytes) file systems on XFS, fixed by [the inode64 mount option](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_What_is_the_inode64_mount_option_for.3F).  But this does not apply to ext3.  It is possible your file system is corrupt; have you (a) checked `dmesg` and (b) run `fsck`?

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions in that folder?

Comment: @nemo: i haven't checked the commands you have specified. I am not familiar with them.
@brandstaetter: yes, i have the permissions to create the file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are writing to parition that is full or broken.
I suggest that you go to single user mode (simplest way to do that is just to write 
init 1)

So ..do this now..

```
mount # to get partitioin device
init 1 # to go to single user mode
fsck -y /dev/yourpartitiondevice
sync
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Although 28% is a pretty large number and it would be very unusual to configure a filesystem like that - but you should check if the remaining space is reserved for root. An `ext2` filesystem hat a number of blocks reserved only for the root user. Run

```
dumpe2fs -h /path/to/blockdevice  | grep -i block
```

and check if the free block count is above the reserved block count.